# vue api $slots.default is not evaluated again when rendered inside slot with v-if

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

Vue slot provides the developers the excellent flexibility.
To communicate parent and child inside slot, to use eventbus is a good way.
But I faced some issues when using $slots api in the parent.
The [$slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-slots) api is not evaluated again when slot content is rendered by [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-if) directive.
For example,

```js
Vue.component('parent', {
    template:'<div v-if="visible"> <slot></slot></div>',
    data(){
    return{
        visible:false
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.$on("triggerVisible", ()=>{
        this.visible = !this.visible;
      //emit event to children in slot
      this.emitEventToChildren();
    })
  },
  methods:{
    emitEventToChildren(){
        this.$nextTick(()=>{
        this.$slots.default.forEach(item=>{
          if(item.child)
            item.child.$emit("eventFromParent", true);
        })      
      })
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('child', {
    template:'<div> <slot></slot></div>',
    data(){
    return{};
  },
  mounted(){
    this.$on("eventFromParent", ()=>{
        this.$el.classList.add("event");
    })
  },
});



var app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
  methods:{
      triggerParent(){
        this.$refs.parent.$emit("triggerVisible");
    }
  }
})
```

```css
div.event{
  background:#999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <parent ref="parent">
    <child>
      <div >
        Child1
      </div>
    </child>
    <child>
      <div >
        Child2
      </div>
    </child>
    <child>
      <div>
        Child3
      </div>
    </child>    
  </parent>
  
  <button @click="triggerParent()">
    Trigger
  </button>
</div>
```

As you can see in the example, when clicking the button at the first time, it works as expected.
Css style class `event` is added to each element.
But when clicking the `trigger` button 2 or more times, `this.$slots.default` is not evaluated again.
If `v-show` is used instead of `v-if`, it works fine.
Please let me know what the reason is.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid directly manipulating the DOM with `this.$el.classList`. For God sake, you are using Vue! Change the template to dynamically render different `class` depending on the component state and either use a global event bus for the events or simply directly call the corresponding component's method (not a good practice but acceptable). Also, do not forget to unsubscribe from the event(s) when the component is unmounted - otherwise you will end up with duplicate handlers in development mode with hot-reloading:

```js
Vue.component('parent', {
    template:'<div v-if="visible"> <slot></slot></div>',
    data(){
    return{
        visible:false
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.$root.$on("triggerVisible", ()=>{
        this.visible = !this.visible;
      //emit event to children in slot
      this.emitEventToChildren();
    })
  },
  beforeDestroy()
  {
    this.$root.$off('triggerVisible');
  },
  methods:
  {
    emitEventToChildren()
    {
      this.$nextTick(()=>
      {
        this.$root.$emit('eventFromParent');
      
      })
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('child', {
    template:'<div :class="classList"> <slot></slot></div>',
    data(){
    return {classList: ''};
  },
  mounted(){
    this.$root.$on("eventFromParent", ()=>{
        this.classList = "event";
    })
  },
  beforeDestroy()
  {
    this.$root.$off('eventFromParent');
  }
});



var app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
  methods:{
      triggerParent(){
        this.$emit("triggerVisible");
    }
  }
})
```

```css
div.event{
  background:#999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <parent ref="parent">
    <child>
      <div >
        Child1
      </div>
    </child>
    <child>
      <div >
        Child2
      </div>
    </child>
    <child>
      <div>
        Child3
      </div>
    </child>    
  </parent>
  
  <button @click="triggerParent()">
    Trigger
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please let me know this.$slots.default is not evaluated based on v-if.